# Adding numbers to a list of strings

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x

Im trying to modify a list of strings so the elements will have element numbers at front starting from `1`.

For example:

`['John', 'Eric', 'Samuel']` becomes `['1 John', '2 Eric', '3 Samuel']`

Here is the code i have so far:

```
for i in range(len(rader)):
    rader[i] = '{}{}{}'.format(i," ",rader[i])
```

This adds a number before but the problem is that it gives the first string number zero, how do I work around this?

Comment: seriously? `...format(i+1," ",rader[i])` ... Python uses zero-based arrays and ranges

Answer (score 3):

You can pass `i + 1` to `format()`:

```
for i in range(len(rader)):
    rader[i] = '{}{}{}'.format(i + 1," ",rader[i])
    #                          ^^^^^
```

But there exists a more elegant way:

```
for i, name in enumerate(rader):
    rader[i] = '{} {}'.format(i + 1, name)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`enumerate`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), just specify `start` and it'll start from `1`:

```
rader = ['{} {}'.format(i,s) for i,s  in enumerate(rader, start=1)]
```

And if you just want to [**`print`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) it that way:

```
print(*('{} {}'.format(i,s) for i,s in enumerate(rader, start=1)), sep=', ')
```

Output:

```
1 John, 2 Eric, 3 Samuel
```

Answer (score -1):

You can pass additional arguments for range function, for example:

```
 for i in range(1,len(rader))
```

[More about range function](http://pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/)

But for this solution you'd need to re-numerate rest of you code though, so it's probably not best idea.

Comment: Which will skip over the first element

Comment: @kdopen: True, it wouldn't work with rest of the code, but I wanted to show that range function can be called with some additional parameters.